# vs code different color for backslash in r string

Tags: python, string, visual-studio-code

in visual studio code, the line below \U and \P and \L are shown in a different color even though they have no effect in r strings
why is that?

```
app = r'C:\Users\Sandramohan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe'
```

[image: vs code image]

Comment: This does not affect your program in any way. Its just some setting of the color theme that you are using.

Comment: @kara so is it a bug in vs code?

Comment: No, it is related to the color theme in vscode. I am not sure if this is a bug or supposed to be this way. If your string wasn't a raw string, you would get an error. Python would interpret `\ ` plus a `U` as bytes and would try to decode it. Maybe your color theme tries to warn you with different colors. Note: I am using [One Dark Pro](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zhuangtongfa.Material-theme) and I dont have different colors.

Comment: no need to use \ in file paths, just use '/' no need to use `r` strings

Comment: @kara I created a normal string with a '\U" and it wasn't in a different color and when I ran the code, it gave me the error you said so I think it is a bug in the color theme

Comment: @kara can you write it as an answer to this question so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the `SynthWave '84` Color Theme. It was configured by this:

```
{
  "name": "Character escape",
  "scope": "constant.character.escape",
  "settings": {
    "foreground": "#36f9f6"
  }
},
```

in this file:

```
C:\Users\{UserName}\.vscode\extensions\robbowen.synthwave-vscode-0.1.8\themes
```

So you can try to switch the Color Theme, some of them do not change that. Or you can modify it by yourself, such as delete it(need to reload the window after you modify it).

Answer (score 0):

It's a [feature](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2445) - apparently a lower 'r' is colored as regex, whereas a capital 'R' is colored as a rawstring.

Use a capital R to get correct coloring:

```py
app = R"C:\Hello\World"
```